# How to get google_interest_data from daily by using pytrends

Tags: python, google-api

I can not understand the specification of the function in pytrends.

A function that specifies the period and keywords, and gets interest of In the specified keyword in google trend as followed

```py
pytrends.build_payload(kw_list, timeframe='YYYY-MM-DD YYYY-MM-DD', geo='JP', gprop='')
```

returned value differs depending on whether the specified period is long or short.

For example, if the period is 1 year, I get the following.

[image: this]

if the period is half a year, I get this.

[image: this]

I want to get daily data for long period (over a year). What should I do?

Comment: which api are you using exactly?

Comment: I use google trend API.
```
from pytrends.request import TrendReq
# API Connection
pytrends = TrendReq(hl='ja-JP', tz=360)
```

Answer (score 1):

The results are scaled based on the period, so that the highest observation in the period specified gets value 100, and the lowest gets a value of 1. Changing from one year to half a year probably changes the max and min values, resulting in a different scaling.

The periodicity appears to be changing as well from your screenshots. Not sure why this happens. To make sure you retrieve daily data I would recommend the get_daily_data method in the dailydata module of pytrends:

```
from pytrends import dailydata
res = dailydata.get_daily_data("cinema", start_year=2019, start_mon=1, stop_year=2021, stop_mon=2, geo = '')
```